# Play Project not compiling correctly in Intellij - routes_routing.scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a simple Play project with one controller (with a route) and a unittest.

When I type "sbt compile test" into terminal it runs fine and the test passes.

I cannot get the solution to compile correctly in IntelliJ however.

Controller: `controllers.nisp.LandingPageController`

Compile error:

```
.../nisp-frontend/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/app/routes_routing.scala 
Error:(37, 18) object LandingPageController is not a member of package app.controllers.nisp 
controllers.nisp.LandingPageController.showLandingPage(),
            ^
```

Directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Did you generate meta files for idea with play: `play idea`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue using the following method:

- Upgrade to Intellij 14
- Upgrade to the latest scala plugin.
- Remove the whole project directory and re-cloned the source.
- Use File -> Import Project -> SBT -> Auto-Import.